# Field error in object 'talent.CandidateProfile' on field 'core': rejected value [null];

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-controller

1:declared field name as a name="db_address1"

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: candidateProfileInstance, field: 'core.db_address1', 'error')} ">
    <label for="core.db_address1">
        <g:message code="candidateProfile.core.db_address1.label" default="Dbaddress1" />
    </label>
    <g:textField **name="db_address1"** value=""/>
</div>
```

1. declared field name as a name="core.db_address1"

Comment: But I see strange '*' and the name of the textfield is name="db_address1". name="core.db_address1" should work

Comment: No @Mr.Cat. Actually these are in bold font. Given by Stack overflow editor

Comment: I see, anyway name="core.db_address1" should work

Comment: Core is embedded right?